# the program does not work when the button is pressed asp.net Web Form 3.5

Tags: c#, button, gridview, asp.net-3.5

I have the following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (!Authorization.OK)
            Response.Redirect("Authorization.aspx", true);

        var operators = OperatorService.GetAllOperators();
        var currentOperator = operators.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Login == Authorization.UserName);

        if (currentOperator == null || currentOperator.Login == null)
            Response.Redirect("Authorization.aspx", true);

        var resultAllRequest = ADCatalogueService.GetAllRequests(currentOperator.FacultyName); 
        if (!Constants.Admins.Contains(currentOperator.FacultyName))
            resultAllRequest = resultAllRequest.Where(x => x.Status == "inProgress").ToArray();

        tabAdmin.Visible = Constants.Admins.Contains(currentOperator.FacultyName);

       // FillData(resultAllRequest);
       //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
}
```

This code works fine if the `FillData` function is commented out and all buttons respond to their events.

**BUT** as soon as I uncomment the `FillData` method, the initial load works fine, the function code is below (all rows of the array have exactly  null fields):

```
private void FillData(RequestAD[] requestAds)
{
        var requestViewModels = new List<RequestViewModel>();

        foreach (var requestAd in requestAds.OrderBy(x => x.LastName))
        {
            var requestViewModel = new RequestViewModel();
            requestViewModel.SecondName = requestAd.SecondName;
            requestViewModel.PhoneNumber = requestAd.PhoneNumber;
            requestViewModel.Email = requestAd.Email;
            requestViewModel.FacultyName = requestAd.FacultyName;
            requestViewModel.LastName = requestAd.LastName;
            requestViewModel.FirstName = requestAd.FirstName;
            requestViewModel.ImageHtml = "<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64," + requestAd.Image + "\">";
            requestViewModel.ButtonsField = "<div value=\"" + requestAd.Status + "\" class=\"buttonContainer\"><input class=\"id\" value=\"" + requestAd.Id + "\"></input><a class=\"tableBtn acceptBtn\" onclick=\"acceptRequest(this)\"></a><a class=\"tableBtn removeBtn\" onclick=\"removeRequest(this)\"></a></div>";
            requestViewModels.Add(requestViewModel);
        }

        requestViewModels = requestViewModels
            .Where(x =>
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.LastName)
                && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.FirstName)
                && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.SecondName)
                && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.FacultyName)
                && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Email)
                && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.PhoneNumber))
            .ToList();

        GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        GridView1.Columns.Clear();

        var columns = new CustomiseColumnModel[] { 
            new CustomiseColumnModel
            {
                ProperityName = "FullName",
                DisplayName = "ПІБ"
            },
            new CustomiseColumnModel
            {
                ProperityName = "SecondName",
                DisplayName = "Прізвище"
            },
             new CustomiseColumnModel
            {
                ProperityName = "FirstName",
                DisplayName = "Ім`я"
            },
            new CustomiseColumnModel
            {
                ProperityName = "LastName",
                DisplayName = "По-батькові"
            },
             new CustomiseColumnModel
            {
                ProperityName = "Email",
                DisplayName = "Емаіл"
            },
            new CustomiseColumnModel
            {
                ProperityName = "PhoneNumber",
                DisplayName = "Номер телефону"
            },
             new CustomiseColumnModel
            {
                ProperityName = "FacultyName",
                DisplayName = "Факультет",
                Width = 350
            },
            new CustomiseColumnModel
            {
                ProperityName = "ImageHtml",
                DisplayName = "Photo",
                Width = 350,
            },
            new CustomiseColumnModel
            {
                ProperityName = "ButtonsField",
                DisplayName = "Дія",
                Width = 100,
            }
        };

        foreach (var column in columns)
        {
            CustomiseColumn(column);
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = requestViewModels;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    private void CustomiseColumn(CustomiseColumnModel columnModel)
    {
        BoundField column = new BoundField();
        column.ItemStyle.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Double;

        if (columnModel.Width != null)
            column.ItemStyle.Width = new Unit(columnModel.Width.Value);

        column.DataField = columnModel.ProperityName;

        if (columnModel.ProperityName == "ImageHtml" || columnModel.ProperityName == "ButtonsField")
            column.HtmlEncode = false;

        column.HeaderText = columnModel.DisplayName;

        GridView1.Columns.Add(column);
}
```

But all the buttons stop working. And in Google I get an error:

> No connection to the site The web page at http://localhost:60226/Request.aspx may be temporarily unavailable or may have been permanently moved to a new web address.
> ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED

I can't debug the code and no button event is fired.

I have another page that is structurally similar to this one and it works - the only difference is that I get different data. Please tell me what exactly could be wrong with my data that I can't catch the error even with a debugger?

Please help me solve this problem